# Incorrect Canonical URL on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, blogs, canonical-link, wordpress.com

I notice the canonical URL in my site is incorrect but I can't understand how to change it.

The web page URL is:
https://ukworklife.com/2023/09/14/recruitment-agencies-for-social-workers-in-the-uk-how-to-find-a-good-one/

But the canonical URL is showing as:

https://ukworklife.com/2023/09/14/recruitment-agencies-for-social-workers-in-the-uk-how-to-find-a-good-one/comment-page-1/#comments

I understand the code that is driving this is the following line in my page header:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://ukworklife.com/2023/09/14/recruitment-agencies-for-social-workers-in-the-uk-how-to-find-a-good-one/comment-page-1/#comments">
```

I don't seem to be able to edit that anywhere however.  Should I be looking for a header.php file to amend this in?

This is a Wordpress.com site, so I am not sure if I even have access to edit the page headers, but it seems it must be possible to set the correct URL as being the canonical one.

Thanks

I tried to find a way to edit the site header, either through a header.php file or a htaccess file (not sure which one would be the best place to do this) but I do not seem to have the ability to find or edit either of these files.

Comment: This is a programming question and is on-topc here, but I tihnk you'd be more likely to get an answer if you deleted here and asked it at [wordpress.se] instead.